# How do you make setup and teardown routines in Make

Tags: makefile

I've searched everywhere, and I can't find this feature. It might just not be possible. I want something the run before and after the recipes are executed. I expected it would look something like this:

```
.BEFORE:
        echo "Hello world"
.AFTER:
        echo "Goodbye cruel world"
foo.txt:
        touch foo.txt
```

Outputting thusly:

```
Hello World
touch foo.txt
Goodbye cruel world
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 4):

```
targets := foo.txt
.PHONY: after before

after: $(targets)
    @echo "Goodbye cruel world"
$(targets): before
before:
    @echo "Hello world" 

foo.txt:
    touch foo.txt
```

---

My previous suggestion ran the recipe for `foo.txt` each time as it depended on a `.PHONY` target. If you're ok with that then you might as well just use double colon rules which will also fix the issue about having multiple targets.

```
targets := foo.txt

$(targets)::
    @echo "Hello world"

foo.txt::
    touch $@

$(targets)::
    @echo "Goodbye cruel world"
```

If `foo.txt` ends up having prerequisites of its own then this issue should resolve on its own, of course the issue now is that the before and after rules will be executed one for each target.

Comment: This is close. It works if I just call make on the default target. I didn't include this in my question, but what if I have multiple targets that I want to target individually? The after target won't get called in that case.